# How to stub ninject's IKernel using Rhino Mocks?

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks, ninject

```
var mocks = new MockRepository();
var access = new Access();
access.ShowRepository = _mocks.Stub<IShowRepository>();
access.ShowRepository.Stub(x => x.GetShows()).Return(new List<Show>());
var kernel =_mocks.Stub<IKernel>();
kernel.Stub(x => x.Get<Access>()).Return(access);
```

This throws an ArgumentNullException:

> Message: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: source

Stack Trace: 
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast[TResult](IEnumerable source)
   at Ninject.ResolutionExtensions.Get[T](IResolutionRoot root, IParameter[] parameters)
   at MediaMover.Unit.Tests.ViewModelTests.OptionsViewModelTests.b__1(IKernel x) in C:\Users\Dave\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Gigatube\MediaMover.Unit.Tests\ViewModelTests\OptionsViewModelTests.cs:line 33
   at Rhino.Mocks.RhinoMocksExtensions.Expect[T,R](T mock, Function`2 action)
   at Rhino.Mocks.RhinoMocksExtensions.Stub[T,R](T mock, Function`2 action)
   at MediaMover.Unit.Tests.ViewModelTests.OptionsViewModelTests.Initialize() in C:\Users\Dave\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Gigatube\MediaMover.Unit.Tests\ViewModelTests\OptionsViewModelTests.cs:line 33

Comment: Which line exactly does throw the exception?

Comment: Last line, particularly, the x.Get<Access>()

Comment: Could you paste the whole stacktrace for the exception? Could be a bug in Rhino Mocks....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this, I had to create a test module and a test provider and pass my mocks through those.

```
class DbAccessProvider : Provider<Access>
    {
        public Access DbAccess { get; set; }
        protected override Access CreateInstance(IContext context)
        {
            return DbAccess;
        }
    }

class TestModule : NinjectModule
    {
        public DbAccessProvider DbAccessProvider { get; set; }
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<Access>().ToProvider(DbAccessProvider);
        }
    }
```

Here is my SetUp from my test:

```
access = new Access();
access.SettingsRepository = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISettingsRepository>();
access.ShowRepository = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IShowRepository>();
access.SettingsRepository.Stub(x => x.GetById(1)).Return(_settings);
DbAccessProvider dbAccessProvider = new DbAccessProvider();
dbAccessProvider.DbAccess = access;
TestModule testModule = new TestModule();
testModule.DbAccessProvider = dbAccessProvider;
var kernel = new StandardKernel(testModule);
target = new OptionsViewModel(kernel);
```